# Multiple HTML tables group by same value in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a HTML table which has results like this: http://prntscr.com/jdp8es

The code used to print out that is this one:

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="basicTable">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Description</th>
       <th>Identifier</th>
       <th>Line Number</th>
       <th>Group Name</th>
       <th>Status</th>
       <th>Created</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="value in requirements track by $index">
       <td><a href="#" ng-click="EditRequirement(value)">{{value.Description}}</a></td>
       <td>{{value.Identifier}}</td>
       <td>{{value.LineNumber}}</td>
       <td>{{value.GroupName}}</td>
       <td>{{value.StatusText}}</td>
       <td>{{value.CreatedDate | date: 'MMM dd yyyy'}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

What I want to achieve dynamically is to have a table for each group name, so for example the Requirement Group Florida will have one table with two results, Chicago identifier will have another table with one result and    NYC Identifier will have another table with one result. Now, the user might add new groups and new requirements in that group so everything will need to be dynamic.

Is that possible with AngularJS?

Comment: Obviously not the same design, but here is a cool example of tables within table cells: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_of_prey#cite_ref-yuri2013_14-0

Comment: Regarding your post history: we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: As an illustration, I count 262 signatures and 343 thanks in your posts, which is an indication of how much volunteer repair work is needed. Please try to write with more brevity.